# How to properly strip silicone wire insulation?

Tags: wiring, temperature, silicone, crimp

[image]

The silicone high temperature double (fiberglass weave?) insulated wire is not getting stripped by wire strippers because it is very soft and seemingly molded onto the wire. How can I remove the insulation properly to prepare for crimping?

Comment: What type of wire strippers are you using?

Comment: I used a self-adjusting wire stripper that typically works well. The issue is that this insulation is very soft. Even with a sharp knife, I can't remove all the insulation; rather, part of the insulation scrapes off like butter, leaving other parts still molded on the wire, between wire strands, etc.

Comment: Looking at that wire it looks like it has been over heated. All the high temp fixture wire I have is smooth and usually strips fine for me, I pull the fiberglass back and then strip I do not use automatic strippers, if yours are adjustable you need to increase the jaw tension. Do not try to use the strippers to cut both the fiberglass and the Teflon.

Comment: @EdBeal Hmm.. it's possible it has been overheated, since the thermal fuse blew. If that softened the insulation and molded it around the wire, it could explain the situation. It really seems stuck onto the wire, not peeling off. Yes, I first carefully cut the fiberglass insulation with a scalpel before trying to strip the silicone insulation.

Comment: Si jackets can be pulled off with fingernails much easier than with PVC jackets.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the next smaller hole on your wire strippers but make sure you don't score the actual conductor. If that doesn't work, use a utility knife and cut from the tip of the wire back down to the white insulation, going around the conductor. If the strands unravel a bit, don't worry, just twist them back after you've scraped the silicone off.

Comment: I used a self-adjusting wire stripper. I also tried cutting or scraping the insulation off with a sharp knife, but it does not come off in one piece or even chunks. The soft insulation practically gets smeared or sliced off, leaving other parts embedded around the wire and between strands.

Comment: @adatum  Try wiping it down with mineral spirits.

Comment: Such as lighter fluid?

Comment: @adatum  Never tried that but should work.